# How can i Use Django with Docker?

Tags: django, docker

So I have a basic django blog application. Which i want to dockerise into django. And one more thing. I am writing my question here because there are live people to answer.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. SO is not live support chat. Your question lacks details and focus - try to show what did you try so far and what did not work. Let others reproduce and troubleshoot your problem by posting a minimal reproducible example. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidance how to ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a cookie cutter for dockerizing your Django application. Here you can read the docs https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment-with-docker.html
you need to pip freeze first so that you could know what your current Django application taking up. And use them as requirements.txt
Benefits of using Django on docker:

- Your code runs on any operating system that supports Docker.
- You save time by not needing to configure system dependencies on your
  host.
- Your local and production environments can be exactly the same,
  eliminating errors that only happen in production.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with reading Dokcer docs in order to understand what and why's: https://docs.docker.com/

Long story short - containers (prular) enable to start every service (Django, database, possible front-end, servers, etc.) in separate container and furthermore, to start them up on any OS of your choice.
Those containers can communicate each other thru host separated docker network.

You will need Dockerfile - to set up service, and possibly Docker-compose (if multiple containers) to manage all the containers running.

Here's example docker setup for Django: https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/dockerizing-a-python-django-web-application